# SSRS How to get 1st date in month with a 1 day lag?

Tags: date, datetime, reporting-services

There are plenty of solutions explaining how to get 1st day of the month of the current month or previous month. But I need my formula to be dynamic to factor in today's date -1 day lag.

For example, today on 8/1/2018  I do not want my parameter to display 8/1/2018, I would like it to have a 1 day lag so it is still displaying 7/1/2018.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking by a one day lag. According to your example, `7/1/2018` represents the previous month (July 1 2018).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression will return the 1 of previous month

```
=dateadd("m",-1,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),1))
```

This expression will return the 1 of current month

```
dateadd("m",0,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),1))
```

Combining with DatePart to calculate whether current day is 1 of month then you can use SWITCH like so

```
=Switch(
   DatePart("d",Now)= 1, dateadd("m",-1,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),1)),
   DatePart("d",Now)> 1, dateadd("m",0,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),1)) 
 )
```

[image]

Change the field's textbox properties like so

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm a little confused with the logic.

Comment: does the dateadd("m",-1 always take the previous month? For example, tomorrow on 8/2/2018 I would like this formula to be dynamic enough to then change the date to 8/1/2018 - not 7/1/2018 anymore.

Comment: @lizfrinko which part?

Comment: sorry, the very first part of the formula "dateadd("M",-1" will that always be taking the previous month? If you wouldn't mind could you briefly explain the formula

Comment: Yes, `dateadd("M",-1` will that always be taking the previous month.  However, I've updated the answer to suit your requirements.

Comment: WOW! This is awesome! Thank you so much for your help!! Really appreciated

Comment: Glad I could help.